# Integrity constraint violation: many to one - cascade all

Tags: hibernate, jpa, cascade, many-to-one

I'm new with hibernate and JPA, and I'm trying to do the next thing:

```
public class Centre extends JpaStandardVersionableEntity {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "sq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sq", sequenceName = SQ_NAME)
@Column(name = "ID_CTR", nullable = false)
private Integer idCtr;
        ...

@JoinColumn(name = "ID_DRC", referencedColumnName = "ID_DRC", nullable = false)
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Address idDrc;

}


public class Address extends JpaStandardVersionableEntity {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "sq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sq", sequenceName = SQ_NAME)
@Column(name = "ID_DRC", nullable = false)
private Integer idDrc;
}
```

With the cascade ALL in order to insert an address when I'm registering a Centre.

But I'm having this error: integrity constraint FK_CTR_DRC violated - parent key not found

Seems this is not working as expected... Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no Adress inside Centre, only a Direccion. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Sorry. It was a typo.

Comment: What is `FK_CTR_DRC`? It seems that the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: FK_CTR_DRC is the relationship between Address and Centre (by id). I also think it has to be something more, but not sure about what or where... I'll let you know asap

Comment: It was completely other thing. A problem with the Addres trigger was giving me wrong ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet is correct. My problem was actually related to the Address trigger. Apologize for the incovenience.